# My custom tooltip in canvas has to display once instead of looping

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

First of all i thank the website and the members who helped a lot in my html5 and javascript queries. Let me get into my problem. In my column chart created using canvas and javascript. I have to include a tooltip. I developed a tooltip for which i have given the code and image below. The problem is the tooltip is not redrawn, it draws again and again.

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload=function() {
            var canvas=document.getElementById('mycanvas');
            var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
            var graphInfo=[{data:[120,130,140,160,180,100],color:'purple',label:["a","b","c","d","e","f"]},{data:[100,120,130,140,150,190],color:'green',label:["g","h","i","j","k","l"]}];
            var width=45;
             function renderGrid(gridPixelSize, color)
    {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        for(var i = 20; i <= canvas.height-20; i = i + gridPixelSize)
        {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(20, i);
            ctx.lineTo(canvas.width-20, i);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        for(var j = 20; j <= canvas.width-20; j = j + gridPixelSize)
        {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(j, 20);
            ctx.lineTo(j, canvas.height-20);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        ctx.restore();
    }
   renderGrid(10, "grey");

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
            ctx.moveTo(20, canvas.height-20);
            ctx.lineTo(canvas.width-20, canvas.height-20);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();

            ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
            ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
            ctx.lineTo(20, canvas.height-20);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.font = "bold 16px Arial";

    function getFunctionForTimeout(j){
                var i=0,currx=30,info=graphInfo[j],x5=j*5;
                var fTimeout=function(){
                    var h=Math.max(info.data[i]-x5,0);
                    var m=info.label[i];
                    ctx.fillStyle='black'
                    ctx.fillRect(currx+(10*x5)+2,canvas.height-h-20,width+2,h-1);
                    ctx.fillStyle=info.color;                   
                    ctx.fillRect(currx+(10*x5),canvas.height-h-21,width,h);                 
                    ctx.fillText(m, currx+(10*x5)+20, canvas.height-5);
                    currx+=120;  
                    i++;
                    if(i<info.data.length)setTimeout(fTimeout,0);
                     canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function onMouseover(e) {
                        var mx = e.clientX - 8;
                        var my = e.clientY - 8;
                        ctx.save();
                        var str='X : ' + mx + ', ' + 'Y :' + my;
                        ctx.fillStyle = '#00ff00';
                        ctx.fillRect(mx + 10, my + 10, 70, 20);
                        ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
                        ctx.font = 'bold 20px verdana';
                        ctx.fillText(str, mx + 10, my + 25, 60);
                        ctx.restore();
                    }, 0);
                };
                return fTimeout;
    }

            for(var j=graphInfo.length-1;j>=0;j--) {
                setTimeout(getFunctionForTimeout(j),2000);
            }
        };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="mycanvas" height="400" width="800" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: setTimeout(getFunctionForTimeout(j),2000); is actually a wrong call. you cannot pass a function call to setTimeout. you can only pass a function object, or a valid javascript executable string.

Comment: May be you can try using events over the canvas to access and make the tooltip dat time... such as onmouseover event and call the tooltip creation?? wat say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HTML5 Canvas is not like SVG or HTML: you can't just add and remove elements, or change their attributes, and expect things to be redrawn for you. When you draw something on a canvas, it is *permanent*. To 'move' something you must erase the canvas (`clearRect()`), and draw the contents again with the tooltip in a new location.

Alternatively, I would suggest *not* using the canvas for your tooltip. Why would you? Instead, create the tooltip as a separate HTML (or SVG) element and move it around. Let the browser take care of redrawing the composite for you.

Comment: Am newbie to html. So am feeling difficult in doing such things.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want `restore` your canvas after you draw a tip box? I think that doesn't work. First let's see the definition of `save/restore`

> context . save()
>   Pushes the current state onto the stack.
>
> context . restore()
>   Pops the top state on the stack, restoring the context to that state.

So, what's "current state"?

From [Specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#drawing-state)

> **Drawing states** consist of:
>
> - The current transformation matrix.
> - The current clipping region.
> - The current values of the following attributes:
>
>   - strokeStyle,
>   - fillStyle,
>   - globalAlpha,
>   - lineWidth,
>   - lineCap,
>   - lineJoin,
>   - miterLimit,
>   - lineDashOffset,
>   - shadowOffsetX,
>   - shadowOffsetY,
>   - shadowBlur,
>   - shadowColor,
>   - globalCompositeOperation,
>   - font,
>   - textAlign,
>   - textBaseline,
>   - imageSmoothingEnabled.
> - The current dash list.

Not contains:

> The current default path and the current bitmap are not part of the drawing state. The current default path is persistent, and can only be reset using the beginPath() method. The current bitmap is a property of the canvas, not the context.

I guess you want some operation like `undo`. I suggest you check `toDataURL` and `drawImage` method, the former returns a Base64 encoded image, and use `drawImage` to draw that image back to canvas. Or, you can [google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=html5+canvas&sugexp=chrome,mod=4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&newwindow=1&sclient=psy-ab&q=html5+canvas+undo&oq=html5+canvas+undo&gs_l=serp.3...993748.995248.1.995560.5.5.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c.vk6_zctBe3E&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=4d5c9bb603a2995d&biw=1600&bih=786)

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code, as last time use the getMousePos() method to get the mouse x and y position and den deliver it to your tooltip..(Now its an alert) :)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload=function() {
            var canvas=document.getElementById('mycanvas');

            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(evt) {
                  var mousePos = getMousePos(canvas, evt);
                  var message = "Mouse position: " + mousePos.x + "," + mousePos.y;
                  //alert(message);
                }, false);

            var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
            var graphInfo=[{data:[120,130,140,160,180,100],color:'purple',label:["a","b","c","d","e","f"]},{data:[100,120,130,140,150,190],color:'green',label:["g","h","i","j","k","l"]}];
            var width=45;
             function renderGrid(gridPixelSize, color)
    {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.lineWidth = 0.5;
        ctx.strokeStyle = color;
        for(var i = 20; i <= canvas.height-20; i = i + gridPixelSize)
        {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(20, i);
            ctx.lineTo(canvas.width-20, i);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        for(var j = 20; j <= canvas.width-20; j = j + gridPixelSize)
        {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(j, 20);
            ctx.lineTo(j, canvas.height-20);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();
        }
        ctx.restore();
    }
   renderGrid(10, "grey");

            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
            ctx.moveTo(20, canvas.height-20);
            ctx.lineTo(canvas.width-20, canvas.height-20);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();

            ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
            ctx.moveTo(20, 20);
            ctx.lineTo(20, canvas.height-20);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.font = "bold 16px Arial";

            function getMousePos(canvas, evt) {
                var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(), root = document.documentElement;

                // return relative mouse position
                var mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.top - root.scrollTop;
                var mouseY = evt.clientY - rect.left - root.scrollLeft;
                return {
                  x: mouseX,
                  y: mouseY
                };
              }
    function getFunctionForTimeout(j){
                var i=0,currx=30,info=graphInfo[j],x5=j*5;
                var fTimeout=function(){
                    var h=Math.max(info.data[i]-x5,0);
                    var m=info.label[i];
                    ctx.fillStyle='black'
                    ctx.fillRect(currx+(10*x5)+2,canvas.height-h-20,width+2,h-1);
                    ctx.fillStyle=info.color;                   
                    ctx.fillRect(currx+(10*x5),canvas.height-h-21,width,h);                 
                    ctx.fillText(m, currx+(10*x5)+20, canvas.height-5);
                    currx+=120;  
                    i++;
                    if(i<info.data.length)setTimeout(fTimeout,0);
                     canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',function onMouseover(e) {
                        var mx = e.clientX - 8;
                        var my = e.clientY - 8;
                        ctx.save();
                        var str='X : ' + mx + ', ' + 'Y :' + my;
                        ctx.fillStyle = '#00ff00';
                        ctx.fillRect(mx + 10, my + 10, 70, 20);
                        ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
                        ctx.font = 'bold 20px verdana';
                        ctx.fillText(str, mx + 10, my + 25, 60);
                        ctx.restore();
                    }, 0);
                };
                return fTimeout;
    }

            for(var j=graphInfo.length-1;j>=0;j--) {
                setTimeout(getFunctionForTimeout(j),2000);
            }
        };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="mycanvas" height="400" width="800" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
    </body>
</html>
```